# Is java.io.BufferedOutputStream safe to use?

Tags: java

At first glance this code seems completely OK

```
BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("1.txt"));
byte[] bytes = new byte[4096];
bout.write(bytes);
bout.close();
```

but if we take a closer look we will see that `close()` is implemented as follows

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      flush();
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Is it possible that due to `flush()` errors are ignored data may be lost and the program will not notice it? There is no mentioning of any danger in `FilterOutputStream.close` (where `BufferedOutputStream` inherits `close()` from) API.

**UPDATE:** To simulate IO error during close() I changed the test to write to a Flash memory, added a 5 secs sleep before bout.close() and while the test was sleeping I removed the Flash from USB. The test finished without exceptions, but when I inserted the Flash and checked it - 1.txt was not there.

Then I overrode close()

```
    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("g:/1.txt")) {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            flush();
            super.close();
        }
    };
```

and ran the test again and got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: g:\1.txt (The system cannot the specified path)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:10)
```

Comment: `FilterOutputStream` typo?

Comment: It shows as a bug in openjdk `close()` method. - Dead store to ignore...

Comment: @Nikolay No its not. BufferedOuptutStream inherits close from there, forgot to mention

Comment: +1 Is this something you are actually seeing or is it just theoretical?

Comment: There are several bug reported on that issue e.g. http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7015589. Personally I think it might be an issue for your application. Workaround I use when working with `BufferedOutputStream` is to call `flush()` before `close()`. This is similar to JDK implementation but in my case I will see errors coming from `flush()`.

Comment: @Tom: Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Flash device are not so reliable as HDD, it is possible 1) remove flash before out.close 2) create out of space situation

Comment: @Tom if you care to post your comment as an answer, I'll delete mine, since you posted the relevant information sooner.

Comment: @pcalcao, that's is fine. Please keep you answer there as it includes more details like `AutoCloseable`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it is, I would reason that calling `close` can indeed make you lose data, since that potential `IOException` is being silently ignored (who on earth knows what went through the developers minds to do that...).

A decent alternative, although it does put the effort on the side of the programmer, is to call `flush` explicitly before `close` (handling the potential `IOException` correctly), like mentioned in a comment by @Tom, particularly in a `try/finally` block.

This problem can be further exacerbated in Java7, due to `AutoCloseable` objects, since you won't explicitly call the `close()` method and this kind of work-around is even easier to slip by.

Comment: probably because they didn't have suppressed exception, so they didn't know how to deal with exception from flush().

Comment: I think it would still be safer to throw the Exception up and let the user explicitly know that something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenJDK 11, the `FilterOutputStream#close()` method (which `BufferedOutputStream` inherits) is a lot more complex:

```java
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (closed) {
        return;
    }
    synchronized (closeLock) {
        if (closed) {
            return;
        }
        closed = true;
    }

    Throwable flushException = null;
    try {
        flush();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        flushException = e;
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (flushException == null) {
            out.close();
        } else {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Throwable closeException) {
               // evaluate possible precedence of flushException over closeException
               if ((flushException instanceof ThreadDeath) &&
                   !(closeException instanceof ThreadDeath)) {
                   flushException.addSuppressed(closeException);
                   throw (ThreadDeath) flushException;
               }

                if (flushException != closeException) {
                    closeException.addSuppressed(flushException);
                }

                throw closeException;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the `flush()` method throws then the exception is now correctly propagated to the caller.

Together with the added locking, `BufferedOutputStream` should now be as safe as possible.