# zip file getting corrupted sometimes from few Android devices

Tags: java, android, ftp, zip, corrupt

What might be the root cause for getting zip file corrupted.??
Am uploading zip to server using FTP from Android. Few files are getting corrupted after they are uploaded. I tried to resolve this in many ways. But I could not. 
Follow this link [FTP zip upload is corrupted sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462522/ftp-zip-upload-is-corrupted-sometimes) for my code snippets.

Thanks in Advance.